# Flatten extranous fields when extracting using LiftJson or Json4s

Tags: scala, lift-json, json4s

I want to extract using LiftJson or Json4s the following Json (not quite but something similar) to the following case classes.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
    "id": "1234",
    "message": "Test",
    "comments": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "4321",
          "content": "Test2",
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

The case classes:

```
case class A(id: String, message: string, comments: List[B])
case class B(id: String, content: String)
```

For the top level I can do: `(val \ "data").extract[List[A]]` to flatten the extra data field. But for the second level one, I don't see I way to use extract DIRECTLY.

Could I use a custom serializer (exemple [here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/47f5ed03b7f1d32ed383c1a92898124cd7fe917a/ext/src/main/scala/org/json4s/ext/JodaTimeSerializers.scala)) or any of the following function (json4s) to remove the extraneous "data" field? Or any idea to make it simple?

```
def mapField(f: JField => JField): JValue
def transformField(f: PartialFunction[JField, JField]): JValue
```

Want I want to avoid is creating others intermidiate case class to extract the data, and then create the shown case class with it.

Comment: Have you tried using transformField using a pattern matching on JFIeld("data", value), returning value directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution a while ago, but haven't had time to reply. I was thinking backward, this is easy:

```
def transformListData(src: JValue, field: String): JValue = {
  src.transformField {
    case JField(x, v) if x == field => JField(field, v \ "data")
  }
}

transformListData(json, "comments")
```

The following would remove the extra `data` and would flatten the list.